# How to prevent the modification of a customized module?

Tags: administrator, custom-module, permissions

Is it possible to prevent the modification of a customized module by another administrator?

If so, how can I implement such a restriction?

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for editing

Comment: If you have conducted any research or made any failed attempts to self-solve,  please include those in your question (as an edit).  Showing your work helps volunteers to better understand your issue, makes your question more attractive to answer, and will give your question a better chance of gaining upvotes.  Please continue to research this issue; if you manage to solve it on your own, please post an answer with the intent to educate.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to build a custom plugin to do that. The way to approach this is to leverage on the Joomla check-in/check-out feature to check-in your modules when you edit them and permanently keep them checked-in (!) That way, any other admin who comes around to change the content of the module won't be allowed to.

In your plugin config, you can add a field to select which module you want to permanently disable others from editing, but if your fellow admins discover the plugin they would probably change the settings too... unless you do something drastic to keep them out of the plugin too.

Comment: This seems like an excellent solution! But I have no experience creating plug-ins.

Comment: A good idea would be to hide the plugin from the list of extensions.

Comment: if your other admins are not super admins then you can hide the module from them.

Comment: So let's start building this plugin. Where do you start?

Comment: You start here https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla

Answer (score 0):

As an interim measure, I have created a custom module and published it to the Admin control panel page which included some text advising not to update a specific component/module. Obviously it doesn’t prevent it happening, but works as a reminder for other admins.